# How can I apply an action to multiple items in a list_filter, without having to do them individually, one after the other?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-suit

Say i have in django admin,

list_filters = ['car_number']

It will give me a list of the car numbers that are in the model for me to choose from one by one.

What I want to do is apply an action to multiple 'car_number's but before I can do that i have to have them visually listed so that I can click the little check box, go to my list of actions and apply the action.

If you have car instances with car_number fields populated from 1-10 and you choose number 6 from the filter list, any car with that number will show up and after it does you can apply an action. But I want to apply an action to both number 6 & 4 without having to do them individually one after the other. How can I  go about this? is there a way to search for them both at the same time? a way to do multiple sections in the filter list?

Just in case it makes a difference, I am running django suit on top of admin

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
cars = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]])
map(action,cars[:,[4,6]])
```

maybe?